# Increase number Python

Tags: python, plugins, notepad++

Sorry for this, I research about 1 day, but I not find the solution.

I have this code and not work

```
number = 1
content = editor.getText()
while "printing" in content:
    content = content.replace("printing", "printing-")
    number += 1

notepad.new()
editor.addText(content)
```

I want to replace 10.000 words in a file with increase number.

Example

from:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
Other example text is simply from user any
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
Other example text is simply from user roger
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
Other example text is simply from user milton
```

to:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing-1
Other example text is simply from user any
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing-2
Other example text is simply from user roger
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing-3
Other example text is simply from user milton
```

The desired word is, `printing-1,` `printing-2,` `print-3,`... to `printing-10000`.

I tried with python plugin in notepadd++ but not work, also I know the option column editor (alt+c) in notepad++ but I can't select 10.000 words.

¿How can I process this task with python in notepadd++ ?

Thanks for reading

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: `content = content.replace("printing", "printing-" + str(number))`

Comment: The problem is all replace word is: printing-1, printing-1, printing-1...  Should be, printing-1, printing-2, printing-3... etc. I test with the last code you wrote the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your while loop with this:

```
split_content = content.split("\n")  #split content into sentences by the newline

new_content = ""

for sentence in split_content:  #split sentence into words
    for word in sentence.split(" "):
        if word == "printing":
            new_content += "printing-%s " % (number)
            number += 1
        else:
            new_content += word + " "

    new_content += "\n"  #put newlines back in to keep original formatting
```

I you need help understanding the code just ask!

Comment: Could you explain why it doesn't work? I am a little unsure of your problem.

Comment: Hi Marky, thanks for your support. The problem is all replace word is: printing-1, printing-1, printing-1... Should be, printing-1, printing-2, printing-3... etc. I test with the last code you wrote the result is the same.  I want to replace in a simgle file with increase number.

Comment: Sorry for giving you bad code I will work on a solution.  Hopefully soon!

Comment: Check the answer I updated it with the correct code so now it should work.   Once again if you have any questions just ask!  Thanks for giving my a good challenge!  Have a great day and God bless!

Comment: If my solution worked I would really appreciate if you would accept my answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry Marky, yesterday I test but not work, I think the problem maybe is my.  Again thanks for your help.  I have a question for your ¿you tried for yourself if the code works?

Comment: I did try the code and it works perfectly for me. Is your question the full code?  What are you getting as output?  You might want to check to make sure the input text is correct.  Also at the bottom of your code you will need to replace the line `editor.addText(content)` with `editor.addText(new_content)` to put the finished output in the editor.  Hope this helps, and once again please ask any question you have.